# convert rows into column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table TableA and with 2 column A & B with entries

Table A

```
|A||B|

|A1|B1|

|A2|B2|

|A3|B3|

|A4|B4|

|A5|B5|
```

I want to split it in 10 column with different column name as

```
|E1|E2|E3|E4|E5|E6|E7|E8|E9|E10|

|A1|B1|A2|B2|A3|B3|A4|B4|A5|B5|
```

It's a part of a query that is associated with different tables that show the association with this table data.It fetches multiple row values that i want show in a single row.

Comment: lookup sql pivot, there are plenty of examples

Comment: What's the expected result if more rows are added to the table?

Comment: You have to use **Pivot** to get rows in column

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: Ms sql Pivot can not transpose more then 1 column at a time. And more , it needs to enumerate the values which enumeration  must consist of all table values here .

Comment: @schlonzo i have already seen that question what i'm trying to do is different . Please look at the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a dynamic sql query.

For the number sequence in the result set column names, we have to add an extra column.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @sql AS varchar(max);

SELECT @sql = 'select ' + STUFF((SELECT
    ',max(case A when ''' + A + ''' then ''' + A + ''' end) as E' 
        + CAST(E AS varchar(10)) +
    ',max(case B when ''' + B + ''' then ''' + B + ''' end) as E' 
        + CAST((E + 1) AS varchar(10))
  FROM (SELECT
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY A
    ) * 2 + 1) - 2 AS E, *
  FROM TableA) t
  FOR xml PATH (''))
  , 1, 1, '') + ' from TableA;';

EXEC (@sql);
```

**Result**

```
+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+=====+
| E1 | E2 | E3 | E4 | E5 | E6 | E7 | E8 | E9 | E10 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
| A1 | B1 | A2 | B2 | A3 | B3 | A4 | B4 | A5 | B5  |
+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+=====+
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, if I understand the content of your table right. Isn't there a primary key or something? 
I'm assuming that the content you showed is all we have:

```
SELECT a1.A AS E1, a1.B AS E2, a2.A AS E3, a2.B AS E4, a3.A AS E5, a3.B AS E6
    a4.A AS E7, a4.B AS E8, a5.A AS E9, a5.B AS E10
FROM TableA a1
JOIN TableA a2 ON a2.A = 'A2'
JOIN TableA a3 ON a3.A = 'A3'
JOIN TableA a4 ON a4.A = 'A4'
JOIN TableA a5 ON a5.A = 'A5'
```

If it's a variable number of rows I would do (asuming that the order of the columns doesn't matter):

```
SELECT A FROM TableA
UNION 
SELECT B FROM TableA
```

And afterwards use the already mentioned `PIVOT`function which SQL-Server provides

Answer (score 0):

For  5 rows exactly, otherwise build dynamic sql.

```
with t as (
  select *, rn=row_number() over(order by A,B) 
  from theTable
)
select 
    r1.A as E1, r1.B as E2, 
    r2.A as E3, r1.B as E4, 
    r1.A as E5, r1.B as E6, 
    r2.A as E7, r1.B as E8, 
    r5.A as E9, r5.B as E10
from t as r1 
join t as r2 on r2.rn=2
join t as r3 on r3.rn=3
join t as r4 on r4.rn=4
join t as r5 on r5.rn=5
where r1.rn=1
```